# Angular2: sending value from component to service

Tags: angular

I would like to send the value from component to service

〇Component

```
import { ColumnEquipedService } from '../../../service/column-equiped/column-equiped.service';

export class SampleComponent{
  public componentCd = `wa9001`;
　　　、、、、、
}
```

〇Service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class ColumnEquipedService {
          componentCd: string;
　　　　、、、、
}
```

want to send the value of `componentCd` in sample component to `componentCd` in ColumnEquipedService.

How its supposed to be done....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a method defined to save the id to the variable

```
export class ColumnEquipedService {
  componentCd: string;
　constructor() 
  saveCompoId(compId:string){
   this.componentCd = compId;
 }
}
```

And then in the component, call the method.

```
constructor(private myService : ColumnEquipedService)

saveToService(){
   myService.saveCompoId(this.componentCd);
}
```